# How to handle unknown number of parameters in node/express

Tags: node.js, rest, express, endpoint

I am using node 8.11.1 and express 4.17.1

I want to have a route where the URL will have at least two optional params and then an unknown number of extra params

Like so

```
app.get('/:category/:cinema/:one?/:two?/:three?/:four?/:five?', function(req, res) {
```

`category` and `cinema` are optional, but still, they are at least there as a couple. The issue is that the rest of them (`one`, `two` etc ) could be one or two or five or 10, according to some user actions. How can I set them if I dont know how many they are?

And how can I get them? I guess I can take the first two by doing

```
const vessel = req.params.vessel;
const calculation = req.params.calculation;
```

How can I get the rest of the params?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a GET request you should use as `params` only the parameter that are mandatory, as for the optional you should use `req.query` (passed in the URL after the `?`

For example: `http://you.url.com?p1=v1&p2=v2&...`